# Can't install psycopg2 on Maverick

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to install `psycopg2` on Mac OS X Mavericks but it doesn't see any `pg_config` file.

Postgres was installed via Postgres.app .

I found pg_config in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/` and put it to `setup.cfg` but still can't install `psycopg2`.

What might be wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to install psycopg2? What's the output?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include *the error message* (s).

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the Postgres.app manual about setting up your PATH? http://postgresapp.com/documentation

Comment: That's ok now. I have installed postgres via Homebrew and set up a default path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install psycopg2 via Pycharm and using Postgres93.app. The installer (when running in Pycharm) insisted it could not find the pg_config file despite the fact that pg_config is on my path and I could run pg_config and psql successfully in Terminal. For me the solution was to install a clean version of python with homebrew. Navigate to the homebrew installation of Python and run pip in the terminal (rather than with Pycharm). It seems pip running in Pycharm did not see the postgres installation on my PATH, but running pip directly in a terminal resolved the problem.